# In React an await can block a render when a props is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I have technical question about React render and await.

If I have a component that has a props called "label" that is used to set the text of a `<p>`, if I press a button that calls an async function that set a timeout of 10 seconds, what happens if the props "label" is changed while the timeout is still active?
The `<p>` value will be updated anyway? Or it will happen after the timeout is finished?
In other words, is a component locked while there is an active await?

I can produce an example if it can makes the question more clear.

```
import { Component } from "react";

export default class TestAsyncComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      label: "BEFORE",
    };
  }

  startAsync = async () => {
    console.log("START ASYNC");
    console.log(await this.foo());
  };

  foo = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("PROMISE FINISHED");
      }, 5000);
    });
  };

  changeLabel = () => {
    this.setState({ label: "AFTER" }, () => {
      console.log("LABEL CHANGED");
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.label}</p>
        <button
          style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px" }}
          onClick={this.startAsync}
        >
          {"START ASYNC"}
        </button>
        <button
          style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px" }}
          onClick={this.changeLabel}
        >
          {"CHANGE LABEL"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I press the START ASYNC button and immediately after that the CHANGE LABEL button (while the await is still active) the label is changed.
My question is now more like: why this happen? Since javascript is single thread, how the await is handled if it doesn't lock the component?

Comment: "I can produce an example if it can makes the question more clear." yes you should do that please. Because your timeout *should* be in a `useEffect` and return a cleanup function that cancels the timeout if the component unmounts, and the answer to "what happens if" changes a lot if you forget to do that.

Comment: Why not try it out and show us that [mcve]?

Comment: "What would happen if..." questions are often best handled by testing it and observing the result.  When you do this, what specific test do you perform and what specific result do you observe?  In what specific way does that result differ from what specific expectation you had and why did you have that expectation?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: It’d be unfortunate if async wasn’t actually async—the whole point of async is that it **doesn’t** block the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

> how the await is handled if it doesn't lock the component?

Why would it?  Nothing is *awaiting* the call to `startAsync()`.  (Nor should it.)

When you click the button to invoke `startAsync` (and the button *doesn't* and *shouldn't* await that call), the asynchronous operation is started and the `setTimeout` is invoked.  None of this is blocking, so control is returned to the UI immediately.

When you click the button to invoke `changeLabel`, it updates state and logs to the console.

Moments later, when the timeout has finished, the function passed to `setTimeout` executes which logs to the console.

Nothing blocking is happening here, nor should it be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not locked while there is an active await, the value will be updated anyway. You can see it here https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot scroll down, there is an example with this. The link I provided is react documentation on this and there is an example and explanation why this happens, just after example of this it says "The state stored in React may have changed by the time the alert runs, but it was scheduled using a snapshot of the state at the time the user interacted with it!"